# Passing data to email template after triggered send in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-template

I am trying to pass the data to the email with a triggered send from Journey Builder.

The template is connected to the same data extension as Journey.

So I have this:

```
%%[ 
 var @data set @data = AttributeValue("Data")
if not empty (@data) then 
  outputLine(concat("Data: ",@data))
else
  outputLine(concat("Data is empty"))
endif 
 ]%%
```

The output is always empty, even though "Data" exists in the Data Extension and has some values. Any clues why it might happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to remove the space between *empty* and *(@data)*

Comment: Oh, my mistake, true. But still empty output.

Comment: If it was a new field added to your DE, try deleting the entry source in your journey and adding it again. Also make sure the field name matches.